# Does this word avalanche from Reddit make any sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context

While scrolling through my saved Reddit posts, I found a 10 months old post from WordAvalanches subreddit. I understand the beginning but I am struggling to understand the last line.

> An hour passed since Thursday find us.
> Awake, eye open.
> Time is four.
> Give in.
> In our past, sins’ thirst defined us.
> A wake I hope in time is forgiven.

I looked up the definitions of *wake* in Cambridge and Merriam-Webster online dictionaries, however I could not find a suitable meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a "word avalanche" is that the same syllables are repeated, or nearly repeated

Here:

```
An hour passed since Thurs  day find  us. Awake, eye ope..n. Time is four. Give in.
In our  past,  sins’ thirst de..fined us. A wake I  hope in  time is for...giv..en.
```

A "wake" is gathering following a funeral. The "meaning" is secondary to the poetry, but roughly  "An hour passed since Thurs  day find  us"  (it is 1am on Thursday morning) "Awake, eye open"  (I can't sleep) "Time is four. Give in"  (Now I've been awake for three hours and I will stop trying to sleep)  "In our past sins' thirst defined us" (This is obscure, I think it means that we were known for wanting (thirsting) to sin) "A wake I hope in time is forgiven. (also obscure, I think it means that I hope to be forgiven of my sins before my funeral)

Or as described by the post author

> 1:00 AM, staring at the ceiling. 3 hours later, now and I need to sleep. I kept thinking back to the mistakes I made. Please, let it pass and secret keep.